# how to congratulate player with using hint and without using it differently

Tags: python, python-3.x

i would like to know how to tell the computer to print different input for player using hint 
     and for someone who doesn't used it to congratulate them

```
import random

words = dict(
    python = "type of snake",
    honda = "type of car",
    spanish = "type of language",)

word = list(words)
var = random.choice(word)
score = 0
chance = 5
x = list(var)
random.shuffle(x)
jumble = "".join(x)

print("the jumble word is :", jumble,)

while True:
    guess = input(" this is my guess :")
    if guess == "hint":
        print(words[var])
if guess == var:
    print("well done you only used ", score,"to guessed it ")
    break
else:
    print("try again")

score +=1

if score == chance:
    print("better luck next time")
    break
```

Comment: Keep a boolean variable is_hint_used and set it to false at start. When a user use a hint flip that to true. When you are at the end you check that boolean to see which message you will print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about adding a boolean, say `hintUsed`, that keeps track of whether or not the user used a hint:

```
hintUsed = False
while True:
    guess = input(" this is my guess :")
    if guess == "hint":
        hintUsed = True # change hintUsed to True !!
        print(words[var])
```

And then, to congratulate:

```
if guess == var:
    if hintUsed:
        #print a message
    else:
        #print another message
    break
```